# Adding recurring event to Google calendar dates are messed up in DST

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm using the Google calendar API to add a recurring event to the Google calendar. In this case, the time zone is set to "Australia/Sydney", the first date of the recurrence is Jan 30 2024. The instances that are created by Google have the correct time (1:30pm) up until the start of Daylight Savings Time, then the times show up as 2:30pm.  They get corrected again after DST ends. All I am doing is setting the RRULE, as below.  Isn't it the responsibility of Google to make adjustments to the time of each instance related to DST?

```
"start": {
  "dateTime": "2024-01-30T22:30:00-05:00",
  "timeZone": "Australia/Sydney"
},
 "end": {
  "dateTime": "2024-01-30T23:00:00-05:00",
  "timeZone": "Australia/Sydney"
},
 "recurrence": [
 "RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;UNTIL=20241218T125900Z;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=-1WE"
 ],
```

The endpoint I am using is:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/<calendar id>/events/import
```